# How to find / modify objects directly on parallel workers in R

Tags: r, optimization, parallel-processing

I have an expensive problem I'm trying to split into pieces.
It's an optimization problem, and consists of an initial expensive setup step, followed by a recursive structure, such that the workers can only perform one step at a time before the results need to be collected, and a new task sent to the workers.

A complicating feature is that an initial setup step for the sub computations that should occur on each worker, *has* to be performed directly on each worker, and cannot be exported to the worker via clusterExport or similar.

I had hoped to be able to use `clusterApply` to assign the outcome of this initial setup to be stored on the specific worker, but can't seem to achieve this.

The first part of my code below shows my current attempts and describes what I would like, the second shows an attempt to see all objects available on the worker and where they are located.

```
   library(parallel)
### What I would like to do:
test2<-function(){
  MYOBJECT <-0
  cl=makeCluster(2,type='PSOCK')
  clusterExport(cl,c('MYOBJECT'),envir = environment())

  clusterApply(cl,1:2,function(x) { #attempt to modify / create MYOBJECT on the worker processes
    y <- x * 2 #expensive operation I only want to do once, that *cannot* be exported to the worker
    MYOBJECT <<- y
    MYOBJECT <- y
    assign('MYOBJECT',y,envir = parent.frame()) #envs[[1]])
  })

    clusterApply(cl,1:2,function(x) MYOBJECT * .5) #cheap operation to be done many times
}

test2()  #should return a list of 1 and 2, without assignment into the test2 function environment / re exporting



#trying to find out where MYOBJECT is on the worker
test<-function(){
  MYOBJECT <-1
  cl=makeCluster(1,type='PSOCK')
  clusterExport(cl,c('MYOBJECT'),envir = environment())

  clusterApply(cl,1,function(x) {
    MYOBJECT <<- list('hello')
    assign('MYOBJECT',list('hellohello'),envir = parent.frame()) #envs[[1]])
  })

  clusterApply(cl,1,function(x) 
    lapply(sys.frames(),ls) #where is MYOBJECT?
  )
}

test()
```

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do. Do you want to access the master process with the child processes?

Comment: I need MYOBJECT on the workers to be unique to each worker, and accessible to later calls to clusterApply. This is normally easy, I could export a list of all the worker specific objects to the cluster -- the tricky bit here is I cannot export said object, it needs to be created on the worker directly.

Comment: I would create RDS files on disk storing what you want with names using the PID of each worker (`Sys.getpid()`).

Comment: Reading the model in from disk for every step is too costly, and anyway faces the same problems as exporting to the cluster -- I need the unique MYOBJECT to persist in memory on the workers.

Comment: So, the only the solution is to do all the computations at once.

Comment: Thankfully, you're wrong and the answer was simply to assign to the global environment.

Comment: In your solution, your assigning to the global environments of the child processes and executing the computations right after the others. So basically the solution I recommend. Or I still don't understand what you want to do. I think you're trying to solve a problem that is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution in the end -- to modify the contents of individual workers in a persistent manner, the assignment within the clusterApply function needs to be made to the global environment.

```
library(parallel)
### What I would like to do:
test2<-function(){
  MYOBJECT <-0
  cl=makeCluster(2,type='PSOCK')
  clusterExport(cl,c('MYOBJECT'),envir = environment())

  clusterApply(cl,1:2,function(x) { #attempt to modify / create MYOBJECT on the worker processes
    y <- x * 2 #expensive operation I only want to do once, that *cannot* be exported to the worker
    assign('MYOBJECT2',y,envir = globalenv()) #envs[[1]])
  })

  clusterApply(cl,1:2,function(x) MYOBJECT2 * .5) #cheap operation to be done many times
}

test2()  #should return a list of 1 and 2, without assignment into the test2 function environment / re exporting
```